# NET 5.0 web project - unable to change connection URL at startup (+ Docker)

Tags: asp.net, .net, docker

I think I pretty much tried every possible way but no matter what I do, my NET 5.0 web app always connects to `localhost:5000`.

At startup I get this:

```
webbackend     | warn: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[0]
webbackend     |       Unable to bind to http://localhost:5000 on the IPv6 loopback interface: 'Cannot assign requested address'.
webbackend     | info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
webbackend     |       Now listening on: http://localhost:5000
webbackend     | info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
webbackend     |       Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
webbackend     | info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
webbackend     |       Hosting environment: Production
webbackend     | info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
webbackend     |       Content root path: /app
```

Even though I have these in place:

`Program.cs`:

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
    Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .ConfigureLogging(logging =>
        {
            logging.ClearProviders();
            logging.AddConsole();
        })
        .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
        {
            webBuilder.UseKestrel()
                      .UseStartup<Startup>()
                      .UseUrls(http://0.0.0.0:80);
        });
```

`appsettings.json`:

```
  "commands": {
    "web": "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel --server.urls http://0.0.0.0:80"
  }
```

`Dockerfile`:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "webbackend.dll", "--urls", "http://0.0.0.0:80"]
```

`docker-compose.yml`:

```
webbackend:
    image: local_webbackend
    container_name: webbackend
    networks:
        - my_network
    environment:
        ASPNETCORE_URLS: http://+:80
    ports:
        - "5001:80"
    expose:
        - "5432"
        - "5001"
    depends_on:
        postgresdb:
            condition: service_healthy
```

I really don't understand what is going on.

I just want this app to connect to `localhost:80` inside its docker container. This port should then be connected to `5001` in the docker-compose network.

Answer (score 0):

First you can change the UseUrls settings in Program.cs IHostBuilder

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
    .ConfigureLogging(logging =>
    {
        logging.ClearProviders();
        logging.AddConsole();
    })
    .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
    {
        webBuilder.UseKestrel()
                  .UseStartup<Startup>()
                  .UseUrls("http://localhost:80/");
    });
```

You can use the default Dockerfile created by Visual Studio or [download](https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/docker/visual-studio-tools-for-docker?view=aspnetcore-5.0) it from Microsoft docs (you can specify all the parameters in docker-compose too, the important thing is to expose port 80, or other port that you have specified in the settings above). The settings are exposing the port 80 by default. In your docker-compose file you can set the settings like this:

```
webbackend:
   image: local_webbackend
   build: <path to generated or created Dockerfile>
   container_name: webbackend
   networks:
       - my_network
   environment:
       ASPNETCORE_URLS: http://+:80
   ports:
       - "5001:80"
   depends_on:
       postgresdb:
           condition: service_healthy
```

With this settings, apps inside the docker network, should connect to your app using URL like: webbacked:80. You can reach the app from your PC using: localhost:5001 and other devices from your LAN: :5001 (for example 192.168.1.100:5001).